# Windows 8 - launch maps app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

We are working on a C# Xaml-based Windows Store app.

We have integrated bing maps within the app, but we were wondering if it were possible to launch the "Maps" app to a certain address?

We don't want to implement full directions, so it would be nice to just provide a button to launch maps so they can do it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [URI Scheme for maps application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj635237.aspx) in conjunction with [LaunchUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx), I think it should do the trick.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Maybe I should have used Bing instead of Google.